# CSOM PeopleManagement Azure Active Directory App

Tags: sharepoint, permissions, azure-active-directory, csom

I am trying to get my Sharepoint users properties and also calling the **PeopleManagement.GetUserProfilePropertiesFor** method, but these come back with the message

> You do not have a permissions to perform this action...

What do I need to change in azure active directory to provide these permissions? I have tried all sharepoint, Graph api, and office 365 required permissions.

Note that this is using a bearer token approach, the cookie approach worked so something is different!?!?

[image]